# C# when opening new form, old one has to stop

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have  new form opening when button is clicked, like this:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
//more code
}
```

Does this mean that, when i click Button8, form2 will be opened, but code after form2.ShowDialog() will not be executed until i close form2?

If this is not the way how to do that, please, can you tell me.

Comment: When [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed. So if you need the following code be executed without closing the dialog, use [`Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show(v=vs.110).aspx). This shows a non-modal window.

Comment: I needed to block code before form is closed, so this is cool to me :D
Thanks!

Comment: So go with `ShowDialog` and always take a look at documentations ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Show();` not `ShowDialog();` That should works.

Comment: I just needed comfirmation, ShowDialog is great for my purpose! Thanks!